# Zerocode: Set system property in host configuration file

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, junit5, zerocode

Configuration:
zerocode-tdd.1.3.2

${host}
At runtime, system property set with -D java option. All is well.

**Problem / What I Need:**
At unit test time, system property not set, and host not resolved. 
App uses Junit and Zerocode, would like to simply configure Zerocode to set the system property.

Example:

**host.properties**

```
web.application.endpoint.host:${host}
web.application.endpoint.port=
web.application.endpoint.context=
```

More Info:
Requirement is for configuration only. Can't introduce new Java code, or entries into IDE.

Any help out there? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available in zerocode version `1.3.9` and higher.
Please use the place holder like `${SYSTEM.PROP:host}` e.g. `${SYSTEM.PROPERTY:java.vendor}` resolves to `Oracle Corporation` or `Azul Systems, Inc.`

Example link:
https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/blob/master/README.md#general-place-holders

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, but not sure if this is the correct way to do so.

**Step 1**: Create a config file and load system properties.

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {

    public Map<String, Object> readProperties(String optionalString) {
        Map<String, Object> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        final String host = System.getProperty("host");

        propertiesMap.put("host", host);

        return propertiesMap;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Add a step (before other steps) to use the loaded properties in the .json file.

**test.json**

```
{
    "scenarioName": "Test ...",
    "steps": [
         {
            "name": "config",
            "url": "com.test.Config",
            "operation": "readProperties",
            "request": "",
            "assertions": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

**Step 3**: Use loaded property in step config

**test.json**

```
 {
        "scenarioName": "Test ...",
        "steps": [
             {
                "name": "config",
                "url": "com.test.Config",
                "operation": "readProperties",
                "request": "",
                "assertions": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "test",
                "url": "${$.config.response.host}/test/xxx",
                "operation": "GET",
                "request": {},
                "assertions": {
                    "status": 200
                 }
            }
        ]
    }
```

That's it, although it is working but I am looking for better approach.

Some possible options I am trying are:

- Common step for load/config (in one place)
- Directly using properties as {host} in json files
- Custom client

Again any help/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My question is why are you trying to access the actual host/port? Sorry for the long answer but bear with me. I think there is an easier way to achieve what you are attempting. I find its best to think about zerocode usage in two ways,

1. live integration tests (which is what I think your trying to do) [meaning this calls a live endpoint / service], or
2. what I refer to as a thintegration test (an integration test but using a mock endpoint / service).

Thinking about it this way gives you the opportunity for two different metrics,

1. when using the mock endpoint / service how performant / resilient is my code, and
2. when using live integration tests what is the rough real life performance (expect a bit slower than external load test due to data setup / test setup).
   This lets you evaluate both yourself and your partner service.

So outside of the evaluation above why would you want to build a thintegration test? The real value in doing this is you still make it all the way through your code like you would in an integration test but you control the result of said test like you would in a standard unit test. Additionally since you control the result of the test this may improve build time test stability vs a live api.

Obviously it seems you already know how to setup an integration test so I'll assume you're good to go there but what about the thintegration tests?

To setup a thintegration test you really have two options,

1. use postman mock server (https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/setting-up-mock/)

   a. more work to setup

   b. external config to maintain

   c. monthly api call limits
2. use WireMock (http://wiremock.org/)

   a. lives with your code

   b. all local so no limits

If you already have integration tests you can copy them to a new file and make the updates or just convert your existing.

**** **To address your specific question** ****

When using WireMock you can setup a dynamic local server url with dynamic port using the following.

```
protected String urlWithPort;

@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort());

protected String getUriWithPort() {
    return "http://localhost:" + wireMockRule.port();
}
```

Note: The above was tested using WireMock version 2.27.1 and ZeroCode 1.3.27

Hope that helps you answer how to dynamically get a server/port for your tests.